# SSL Certificate not showing when request is sent to the application

Tags: rhel, java, certificates

i have a java keystore which 2 certificate chains has been installed. a CSR was generated and signed by a CA and both certificate with corresponding CA's were installed. however when i send a request to the application on the port, only one certificate is displayed but i want both certificates in the keystore to be displayed so i can authenticate against the preferred certificate.

i need assistance on this

Comment: Though the English is not excellent, this seems fairly clear and specific to me. But I don't see anything about it that relates to RHEL.

Answer (score 0):

Aside: a CA does not sign a CSR; it signs a certificate which is *partly* based on the CSR but partly not (and both parts are important).

You say '**a** CSR was generated'. If you truly created one CSR (for one key) and got two certs (each potentially with chain) for that CSR, and installed both cert chains to the one privatekey entry in your store, then the second one replaced the first one and you only have the second one in your store.

I assume you instead generated two privatekeys and two CSRs (one for each key) and for each CSR got a cert chain and installed it to the corresponding privatekey, so you actually have two privatekeys with different cert chains and want to see both. If in doubt, use `keytool -list [-v]` to check.

**The SSL (now TLS) protocol doesn't do that**; the server sends only one 'entity' (server) cert, with its chain certs if any, and proves the corresponding privatekey, in one handshake.

You *may* be able to do two requests, each of which gets *one* of the cert chains you want:

- If the certs have different Subject/SAN names AND your client uses the SNI extension, which recent browsers do but other software may or may not, Java 8 server will prefer the cert matching the SNI. Most clients (but not OpenSSL!) always make SNI the same as the hostname connected to, so you may need to (temporarily?) alter your name resolution to point multiple hostnames to the same server, for example with your `hosts` file or unbound or similar.
- If the certs are for different key types (RSA, DSA, EC) and the client offers only ciphersuites that use one key type, Java server will use the cert for that key type. Some clients allow you to easily control the ciphersuites offered, some do not.
- Similarly, if the cert chains use different (sets of) signature algorithms and the client implements TLS1.2 with the SignatureAlgorithms extension then Java 7+ server will prefer a cert chain that satisfies SigAlgs. But I don't know any clients that let you easily select SigAlgs, and anyway CAs offer little choice what signature algorithms are used in chains for certs they issue.